# Posting mutipart/form-data with array of ints in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to post a file to a .Net Core controller action with the following model (paired down from the actual class):

```
 public class UploadDocumentModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int[] Ids { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
      

    }
```

Here is the action that receives the post:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDocument([FromForm]UploadDocumentModel documentModel)
```

The problem is that when I use Swagger or Postman to test it out while passing in an array of Ids, .Net Core throws a validation error:

```
"errors": {
        "Ids": [
            "The value '1,2' is not valid."
        ]
    },
```

I could accept the Ids as just plain string (comma separated list of ids) and then parse them into an array of ints but I suspect I am missing something else here. Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo to pass file and an array with Postman:

UploadDocumentModel:

```
public class UploadDocumentModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int[] Ids { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDocument([FromForm]UploadDocumentModel documentModel) {
            return Ok();
        }
```

formdata:

[image]

result:
[image]

Comment: That works fine when you are not posting a file (IFormFile) in addition to the other data. It's when you are posting a file and additional data with an array of ints that I am having an issue with.

Comment: I have updated my answer,and it can also work to pass file with an array.